# Marking File/Path Folder as required in order to proceed in Form Designer?

Tags: forms, uipath, uipath-activity, form-designer

I’m making an interface where the user has to choose the path for two files. Everything works as intended BUT in order remove the user error (pressing the Proceed button without the files) I need to make the input fields required in order to be able to proceed. The fields have to be in the same window.
[Said form window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swBU3.png)

Any thoughts?

Comment: The form should have an output property called Dismissed which is a boolean and set to `True` where the user hasn't entered any data.  You could use this to check if no input is provided.  It'd be easier to try and help if you include a screenshot of your process flow and the form properties

Comment: I've uploaded the screenshot to imgur. https://imgur.com/a/SAgrGQK
Dismissed will be true if the user clicks the window close button without touching anything within the form.

Comment: can you use flow chart activity and inside it use form activity. After exection of form activity check result and if no file was selected i.e. no result then show error to user and loop back. You can you Do While loop as well instead of flow chart.

Comment: If anyone comes across this. I’ve used Is Match Activity so if “introducetiCaietulDeSarcini”:"" = True - log message - error something - go again using a flowchart.

Thank you for your replies, I've tried all of your suggestions!